# Datatypes and numbers in Mathematica

Tags: big-numbers, data-types

I have some questions about numbers in *Mathematica*:

- Does *Mathematica* work with datatypes like `int`, `long`, `short` or `byte` in C#?
- What is the biggest number that *Mathematica* can calculate?

Comment: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/RepresentationOfNumbers.html

Comment: I'll say it now: don't treat it like C#; it's a rather different paradigm we have in place. In particular, let me advise you to read about heads in *Mathematica*...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first Q (since i'm a C noob): [Mathematica  c#](https://www.google.com/search?q=Mathematica+%C2%AE+with+datatypes&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=mathematica+c%23) and the Documentation Center [Types of Numbers](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/TypesOfNumbers.html)

Your second Q;

> $MaxMachineNumber is the largest machine-precision number that can be
>   used on a particular computer system.

```
$MaxMachineNumber

(*
1.79769*10^308
*)
```

> $MaxNumber gives the maximum arbitrary-precision number that can be
>   represented on a particular computer system.

```
$MaxNumber

(*
1.605216761933662*10^1355718576299609
*)
```

Infos relevant for

> "10.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (December 4, 2014)"

with 32 GB 1600 MHz DDR3, so this type of Q/A depends on your System anyway.